# Window dot open method is getting page can't be displayed issue on download csv file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iis-7, https

we are using `window.open('https://cerrtificate-name/csv/394099.aspx?mode=-1')` to download a `csv` file from server. It was working good when I use `http` but failed to work on in the `https` certificate enabled server.

It was given "page can't be displayed issue".

In the below lines are used in 394099.aspx  to transmit the csv content

```
String contenttype  = "application/octet-stream";
string strSourceFilepath = "d:\\myfile.csv";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", strContentDisposition+"; filename=myfile.csv");                        
Response.ContentType = contenttype
Response.TransmitFile(strSourceFilepath);
Response.Flush();
```

Why this strange behaviour for SSL certificate enabled version? Please help me or advise something to sort it out.

```
WebServer          : IIS 7.0
Server Language    : ASP.NET
SSL                : Enabled
```

Comment: And what happens when you visit the page to check the certificate validity? I assume you have?

Comment: I've valid certification. The same certificate URL is working for other things like page login,etc. only problem with downloading CDR

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't your content type be: Content-type: text/csv

Comment: This would have been better suited as a comment.  Answering a question with a question isn't a best-practice on SO.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry about that. Should I still change it now?

Comment: You could try to delete the answer but, I think you will need a moderator to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

See the following

If you use IE, you may solve the problem.

[C# BinaryWrite over SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356548/c-sharp-binarywrite-over-ssl)

Or

[Downloading a file over https in IE8, using ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682123/downloading-a-file-over-https-in-ie8-using-asp-net)